# Bash regular expression pattern matching spaces, within double brackets test, using "~=" operator

Tags: bash, regular-expression, string

Simply said, I just can't find a way to match a variable against some pattern containing spaces.

Here is what I expected to work (echo 'ok' string)

```
item='foobar baz'
pat=".+bar baz"
if [[ "$item" =~ "$pat" ]] ; then
    echo ok
fi
```

Adding/removing quotes around $pat does not seem to make any difference.
I get those two erros below:

```
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `~='
```

Could someone please help me pointing out what I am doing wrong here ?
Should I put the pattern right away (without any quotes/double quotes, nor variable reference) ? If that is the case, then how can I put spaces in ? (using reg-exp matching, not an alternative)

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax error is self-explanatory i.e. you have used `~=` instead of `=~`.

Regarding the Regex pattern, just use `$pat` (and also `$item`), being a shell builtin `[[` can handle word splitting:

```
item='foobar baz'
pat=".+bar baz"
if [[ $item =~ $pat ]]; then
    echo ok
fi
```

When you use double quotes around `$pat` i.e. `"$pat"`, the Regex tokens `.` and `+` are treated literally.

**Example:**

```
$ item='foobar baz'; pat=".+bar baz"; if [[ $item =~ $pat ]]; then echo OK; fi
OK
```

Comment: `pat="^.+bar baz$"`

Comment: @Stphane check edits

Comment: @heemayl Thank you for your time / code review .. No error anymore ! But I don't get the ok `:p`

Comment: @Stphane yes..check edits..which version of `bash` you have?

Comment: @heemayl `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @Stphane thats good..as you can see i can not reproduce your problem..

Comment: @heemayl I missed stripping out quotes around the `$pat` variable, after `=~` operator ! The problem was between the chair and the keyboard .. I probably need some rest ! Once again, thank you for the code review `:)`

Comment: @Stphane No problem :)