# Bash - Regex to match tuples of numbers

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

I want to check if a string that has been written to a variable in bash via the read command is a tuple of two numbers. To my knowledge, this should be possible with

```
if [[ "$input" =~ "$regex" ]]; then ...
```

for a tuple of two numbers, separated by at least one whitespace and any number of whitespaces before and after, I tried

```
$regex="^ *[0-9]+ +[0-9]+ *$"
```

which should match

```
12 123
  23 3246543
123     345     
     34      23
1 234
```

but not

```
123 123 123
1235124
123w123 123
etc.
```

however, this doesn't work...

Comment: Can you give some sample data? Also - do you _need_ to anchor the regex?

Comment: I added some examples, does that make it more clear? As for the anchors, no, I guess they are not necessary...

Comment: Drop the quotes if using bash 3.2 or above: `[[ "$input" =~ $regex ]]` or use the `compat31` option (or use `zsh`)

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, that was pretty much it... Do you want to rewrite this as a short answer?

Comment: related, if not exact dupe http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251381/68757

Comment: @muru not sure - in that possible duplicate the issue was `=` vs `=~`. Here it's about misquoting when trying to use `=~`.

Comment: @roaima are we looking at the same question? In that q too OP is using `=~` with quotes, which is the problem

Answer (score 0):

*POSIX* shell script function, uses parameter expansion to get first and second number, `-eq` succeeds only if there are two arguments that are both the same number, (and fails there's fewer or more arguments, or if any contain letters), and `!=` to check for a space. 
Returns *true* only if it's a two number tuple:

```
is_tup() { [ ${1% *} -eq ${1% *} -a \ 
             ${1#* } -eq ${1#* } -a "${1% *}" != "$1" ] 2> /dev/null ; }
```

Test:

```
echo '12 123
  23 3246543
123     345     
     34      23
1 234
123 123 123
1235124
123w123 123' | 
while read x ; do is_tup "$x" && a=yes || a=no ; printf '%s\t%s\n' $a "$x" ; done
```

Output:

```
yes 12 123
yes 23 3246543
yes 123     345
yes 34      23
yes 1 234
no  123 123 123
no  1235124
no  123w123 123
```